# how to generate header of function with visual

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, editor, hotkeys

Do you know if there is a way to generate comment with hotkey in visual ?

Here is an exemple :
When I press "ctrl + h" (for exemple) I would like the following lines are generated :

```
        /*
         * Creation: 2012-07-24 by user
         * Modification: 2012-07-25 by user
        */
        Int myFunction()
        {

        }
```

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried typing `///` for the XML documentation? (You will need `Generate XML documentation file` ticked in your **project** options)

Comment: no I would like to have this comment into my code (above my function)

Comment: If the checkbox is on, then typing `///` directly above the function will place a formatted comment block (which is then used in the intelisense for that function when being used elsewhere in the code). It's not exactly what you're after, but I think it would be useful to you from what I can tell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Generate XML documentation file` ticked under the **project** options (this is not an IDE or solution option, but a project one) then you can type `///` directly above a function.

This will create the following example comment, which you can fill in the details between the XML tags...

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public Lookup FindById(int id)
{
```

The information you put in between the tags will then be used by Visual Studio to populate intelisense information when using the function in other parts of your code.  It can also be used with properties, enum, etc.

It's not exactly what you're asking for (including usernames, dates, etc), but I believe it could be an option for you.

(Note, this is also available for VB.NET, and uses `'''` instead)

Comment: is it also available for C++ ?

Comment: @Yumino, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that question - I do not have C++ installed in my version of VS2010 (I never have to deal with it)... but my guess is that it would - try it and see